# Custom Drawing TPopupMenu doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Using C++ Builder 2009.  Experimenting to see if I can improve `TPopupMenu` (also `TMainMenu`) for Windows 11

My `AdvancedDrawItem` function is never called.  I'm not sure why.  Am I missing something silly?

[image]

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Init done here for the sake of small code sample
    PopupMenu1->OwnerDraw = true ;
    PopupMenu1->Items->OnAdvancedDrawItem = AdvancedDrawItem ;
    
    
    PopupMenu1->Popup(Left + Button2->Left + 50, Top + Button2->Top + 50) ;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::AdvancedDrawItem(TObject *Sender, TCanvas *ACanvas, const TRect &ARect, TOwnerDrawState State)
{
    TMenuItem *Item = (TMenuItem*)Sender ;
    
    TTextFormat TF = TTextFormat() << tfVerticalCenter << tfSingleLine << tfEndEllipsis << tfLeft ;
    
    ACanvas->TextRect((TRect&)ARect, (String&)Item->Caption, TF) ;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PS. In a different project with a lot more complexity, I do get it to fire in an object that inherits from `TPopupMenu`.  I'm thoroughly confused at the moment as to why I can't get this simple code to work.  However, I'm starting to realize that this is a task and a half since `DrawThemeBackground()` doesn't appear to do anything during this event, and I was sort of relying on that.  Also, keeping into account shortcuts, icons, etc while painting is going to be a PITA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `PopupMenu1->Items->OnAdvancedDrawItem = AdvancedDrawItem ;`

This is wrong. You need to assign the `OnAdvancedDrawItem` handler to each individual *visible* `TMenuItem` in the menu (ie, `test1` and `test2`), not to the `TPopupMenu::Items` collection that owns the items.

> `ACanvas->TextRect((TRect&)ARect, (String&)Item->Caption, TF) ;`

Both typecasts are wrong.

Since you are not using a `TF` flag that allows `TextRect()` to modify the parameter values (`tfCalcRect` or `tfModifyString`), you can use `const_cast` to replace the first one:

`const_cast<TRect&>(ARect)`

But, there is technically no legal way to convert an rvalue (such as the return value of `TMenuItem::Caption`) to an lvalue reference, a variable or function call is required, so just use a variable:

```cpp
String str = Item->Caption;
ACanvas->TextRect(const_cast<TRect&>(ARect), str, TF);
```

In which case, you may as well use a variable for the 1st parameter, too:

```cpp
TRect rect = ARect;
String str = Item->Caption;
ACanvas->TextRect(rect, str, TF);
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, I see now what I overlooked.  If you know of a cool trick to somehow make (ancient compiler) `TPopupMenu` paint the background *before* it paints the icon and make the text color `clHighlightText` when selected, do let me know and I'll post a Q ;)

Comment: Why can't you handle all of that in your `On(Advanced)DrawItem` handler?

Comment: Well, that's what I fear it will come down to.  I was still hoping for a miracle :) There's a lot to consider.  Shortcuts, icons etc.